# Export HTML table or CSV or XML or RTF to excel using javascript in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, xml, csv, xlsx

I am trying to convert an HTML table or XML or CSV or RTF file into Excel using plain JavaScript with Internet Explorer.
It seems that none of my Javascript or jQuery function works in IE.
I have run the same code with other modern browsers without problems.
Could you please give me a simple example that actually works in Internet Explorer?

Comment: Can we see the secret code you're trying to run in IE?

Comment: Also, can you explain why you are trying to support Internet Explorer? Why not Edge? Microsoft is ending support for IE soon: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2021/05/19/the-future-of-internet-explorer-on-windows-10-is-in-microsoft-edge/

Comment: There is no secret code.. I have tried simple examples found on the web and modify them but I always get the error "JavaScript function is undefined" .. I have also tried Edge but with limited sucess...I will post an example..

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
<table id="tblData">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>john@gmail.com</td>
        <td>USA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Michael Addison</td>
        <td>michael@gmail.com</td>
        <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sam Farmer</td>
        <td>sam@gmail.com</td>
        <td>France</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="exportTableToExcel('tblData')">Export Table Data To Excel File</button>

<button onclick="exportTableToExcel('tblData', 'members-data')">Export Table Data To Excel File</button>

<script>
function exportTableToExcel(tableID, filename = ''){
    var downloadLink;
    var dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var tableSelect = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
    
    // Specify file name
    filename = filename?filename+'.xls':'excel_data.xls';
    
    // Create download link element
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    
    if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
        var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', tableHTML], {
            type: dataType
        });
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
    }else{
        // Create a link to the file
        downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;
    
        // Setting the file name
        downloadLink.download = filename;
        
        //triggering the function
        downloadLink.click();
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Lets say I have a simple HTML table.. This example does not work in IE.. It works with Edge though.
I want to do the same with other files (XML, CSV, RTF).
Unfortunetly the web platform I use works only with IE..